# Issue ierating through individual items in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have got an array collection whereby I am iterating through each of them individually and get each id so as to display in the view. When using a foreach loop I only get the 1st id but I want to get all of them depending on the number of items in the array. For instance in the array before I should get 4 ids.

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => "157"
    "unit_sales_managers" => array:7 [▶]
    "policies" => array:3007 [▶]
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => "73401"
    "unit_sales_managers" => array:8 [ …8]
    "policies" => array:2226 [ …2226]
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => "0"
    "unit_sales_managers" => array:1 [ …1]
    "policies" => array:162 [ …162]
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => "76300"
    "unit_sales_managers" => array:1 [ …1]
    "policies" => array:1 [ …1]
  ]
]
```

**Iterating in the view**

```
 @foreach ($asm as $asms)
     <div class="panel-group" id="hierachy">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1"> {{ dd($asms['id']) }}</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: How do you iterate?

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: It looks like you're using a template library, not ordinary PHP.

Comment: Element IDs needs to be unique. You're creating the same `id="collapse1"` every time.

Comment: like this? $array= array_column($asm, 'id');

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function.

```
$ids = array_map(function ($item) {
    return $item['id'];
}, $array);
```

Which will return a new array after applying the callback on the old one.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `dd()`, script will be dump first element content and stop execute. Just remove `dd()` to display all elements.

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1"> {{ $asms['id'] }}</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think nested foreach will do the trick.

```
@foreach ($asm as $asms)
    @foreach ($asms as $a)
      <div class="panel-group" id="hierachy">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1"> {{ dd($a['id']) }}</a>
         </h4>
         </div>
         <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```